# ValueInjecter Null Values

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

I'am using ValueInjector(3.x) over AutoMapper but I have some questions.

First, I don't understand the difference between `UnflatLoopInjection` and `FlatLoopInjection`.

Also i want to set values in complex types.

```
Class Product {
   public string Id { get; set; } 
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public Category Category { get; set; }
}

Class ProductDTO {
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public Category Category { get; set; }
}

var product = repository.Get(id);
product.InjectFrom(dto);
```

The problem is my `product.Category` already have some properties with values and using InjectFrom the value injector replace the `product.Category` to `dto.Category` replacing the entire category even replacing to `null`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flattening is when you go from

`Foo1.Foo2.Foo1.Name to Foo1Foo2Foo1Name`

unflattening the other way around

I understand that you want to avoid injecting when the source property is Null

for this you can create an injections like this:

```
public class AvoidNullProps : LoopInjection
{
    protected override void SetValue(object source, object target, PropertyInfo sp, PropertyInfo tp)
    {
        var val = sp.GetValue(source);
        if(val != null)
        tp.SetValue(target, val);
    }
}
```

and use it 
`res.InjectFrom<AvoidNullProps>(src);`

---

you could also use the Mapper:

```
 Mapper.AddMap<ProductDTO, Product>(dto =>
            { 
                var res = new Product();
                res.Id = dto.Id;
                res.Name = dto.Name;
                if(dto.Category != null && dto.Category.Id != null) 
                   res.Category = Mapper.Map<Category>(dto.Category);

                return res;
            });

  var product = Mapper.Map<Product>(dto);
```

Comment: It works in simple scenarios... but in my case if my product.Category.Id already has a value and my `productDto.Category.Id = null` then my `product.Category.Id` will be null because it substitutes the `product.Category` to `productDto.Category` and I want a deep injection.

But thanks anyway :)